# Removing Lingering Provisioning Profiles

Tags: xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to remove all of my personal provisioning profiles that were loaded into my work computer when I added my account to Xcode.

I've already removed my account from the Accounts tab in settings.

I deleted all profiles in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

I deleted and reinstalled Xcode. No matter what I do, the provisioning profiles will still appear in Build Settings > Provisioning Profile.

Is there another place where these are stored? I am using Xcode 6.4

**EDIT:**

I've made some progress. In the folder `/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode` (admin is my username), I searched for one of the profiles by ID using

```
sudo find . -type f -exec grep -l '2322c49f' {} +
```

where `2322c49f` is the beginning of the ID. This showed me that this ID was in the file `DeveloperPortal 6.4.db-wal`. When I opened it, it showed a lot of characters that couldn't be rendered, so I thought maybe it's a binary file. Then scrolling down was a plist embedded in it. The plist consisted of all the profiles. I delete this file and the two other similar files, listed below

```
DeveloperPortal 6.4.db      DeveloperPortal 6.4.db-shm
```

I restarted XCode, it regenerated these three files, but the profiles continued to appear in them

Answer (score 1):

I found another location where profiles are kept

```
/System/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

I deleted the profiles from here and that solved the issue